# Cucumberjs how do you break up the world.js into smaller files

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs

Okay, so I have an automation repo that is using cucumberjs.  My world.js file has gotten rather large and I'm trying to divide it up so it is easier to organize.  I've tried to dividing into files and combining it via the prototype -

```
// features/support/world.js
const foo = require('./foo.js');

class customWorldObject {
   bar(number) {
      //do stuff;
   }
}

customWorldObject.prototype.foo = foo;
setWorldConstructor(customWorldObject);
```

but later in in the step functions

```
// features/support/steps.js
const { Given, When, Then } = require("@cucumber/cucumber");
const assert = require("assert").strict;


When("I increment the variable by {int}", async function (number) {
  this.bar(number);
});

When("the variable should blah blah blah", async function() {
  this.foo();
});
```

When I run this puppy, it doesn't seem the added function

TypeError: this.foo is not a function

So how can I correctly break the cucumberjs world object into separate files?

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have better luck using:

```
Object.assign(customWorldObject.prototype, foo);
```

instead of:

```
customWorldObject.prototype.foo = foo;
```

not sure why - they almost seem to do the same.